# Local Network: An unexpected condition occurred. Not all of your requested changes in settings could be made

Tags: networking, ip, windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1709

All conditions being exactly the same except Windows 10 versions (1607 vs. 1709). When I attempt to set a static IP address in 1709 I get an error message stating **"an unexpected condition occurred. Not all of your requested changes in settings could be made."** When I attempt the exact same change on 1607 I do not receive this error message.

**Conditions:**
Complex enterprise network but testing in this instance is on same device model, same OU, same network, same end user credentials, same applications, no virtual machines, just different OS versions.

[image: Image Of Error]

Comment: Unfortunately, no two Windows installations are the same. If that were the case, things wouldn’t regularly break in the most ridiculous ways. So I suggest just reinstalling Windows. You could also try deleting the network adapter in Device Manager then letting it reinstall. That *might* help un-break some stuff.

Comment: Look at the event logs and share anything you think is relevant to this issue. Try netsh interface context and if you know to use procmon please capture something for us and share. The settings are made to certain keys in registry. If you can take the pains to find out where these are especially the ones in "Services" key , find out if you any permission issue persists at the time of this failure. You can set a value and see. Finally you can also try unchecking and re-checking the "Internet protocol version 4" option you are seeing right there. This might even fix the issue.

Comment: What happens if you try to set the static IP using `netsh`?

Answer (score -1):

**an unexpected condition occurred. Not all of your requested changes in settings could be made**

*Local Network: An unexpected condition occurred. Not all of your requested changes in settings could be made*

**: Hay, guys!** I was Getting this error {DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN} when trying to download the Epic Games Launcher. After some investigation, it turned out that the issue was related to DNS, and it was taking the DNS from WMware. To resolve this, all you have to do is delete it(the VM), and it will run correctly.

[Note: After deleting the VM, set a static DNS from the TCP/IPv4 settings with DNS=8.8.8.8 and alternative DNS=8.8.4.8.]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please focus on making your answers fit the questions that were asked. Going around posting the same story on every question that has a given tag or that came up in a search is not a good practice here.